# Create a dictionary of dictionaries with string numbers

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary of dictionaries with a list of numbers in the last one. I'm adding the numbers 1 - 254 as strings to a dictionary so the number is the key and the value will be another dictionary with the keys as 1 - 254 as strings again and finally a list as the value with the numbers 1 - 254 as strings. I cant figure out how to do this. There will be a total of around 16 million elements when its all been executed. I can't figure this out.

```
def fill_ip_list(dict_list):
    """ Create an IP list of lists approximately 15 million numbers from 1 - 255, three lists deep. """

    ips = []
    count = 0

    print("Populating the IP store. Please wait...")

    for octet_one in dict_list:
        ips.append({str(octet_one["prefix"]): {}})
        for octet_two in octet_one:
            for x in range(1, 254 + 1):
                octet_one.update({x: {}})
    print(ips)
```

Output:

```
[{'1': {}}, {'2': {}}, {'3': {}}, {'4': {}}, {'5': {}}, {'7': {}}...
```

Expected output:

```
[{'1': {'1': '1'}, {'2': '2'}, {'3': '3'}...}]
[{'2': {'1': '1'}, {'2': '2'}, {'3': '3'}...}]
[{'3': {'1': '1'}, {'2': '2'}, {'3': '3'}...}]
[{'4': {'1': '1'}, {'2': '2'}, {'3': '3'}...}]
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call this function fill_ip_list? what value do you expect in the parameter dict_list?

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: The dict_list is a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains a key which is a string and each dictionary key is a number ranging from 1 - 254. The idea is to choose a random key 1 - 254 and the a random number from the value of that key which is another dictionary of keys and then that dictionaries keys is a list of numbers. The idea is to generate a random network number i.e 243.54.7

Comment: In the edit I added the output for the first list of dictionaries. I want the curly braces (the value) to be filled again with dictionaries with keys as numbers from 1 - 154

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just create three random numbers and keep track of the ones that have been chosen.  So you would have num1 = str(random.randint(1,254)) and num2 would be same and num3 would be same.  Then your IPaddr = num1 + "." + num2 + "." + num3.  You could keep track of IPaddresses in a listOfIPAddress so that you never had to worry about duplication.

Comment: It would be easier yes but it would consume far more time when the list gets to big. I already have a working program that does exactly that but it needs improving. This way once complete will be far more efficient.